# Cmake to recognize library path installed in /usr/local

Tags: linux

I'm trying to build OpenCV by following [Kdenlive's compilation document](https://community.kde.org/Kdenlive/Development/KF5).
At cmake step, cmake cannot find ffmpeg's library.
How can I address cmake to find ffmpeg?

Command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ git clone https://github.com/mltframework/mlt.git
$ mkdir opencv/build
$ cd opencv/build
$ cmake .. -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules
```

Output of cmake:

```
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
```

Platform is Scientific Linux 7.4 and
I have installed ffmeg and it's library under '/usr/local/lib' but it seems that cmake couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to build OpenCV with ffmpeg support? to me, it reads like they are two separate parts (1) OpenCV for the motion tracker (2) an up-to-date  FFMPEG. Regardless, IIRC ffmpeg is turned off by default in the OpenCV cmake build - so at a minimum you'll need to add `-DWITH_FFMPEG=ON` and then see what sub-parts it still complains about

Answer (score 3):

Does your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable include `/usr/local/lib`?

You can check with `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

The safest way to add it, if missing, is:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

this will add the `/usr/local/lib` to the existing directories in.